# How to sort a map of list having key-value pairs?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am getting a list of results in a map for a particular key. How to sort it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user: what are the those results, i mean object type.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to sort keys then go for [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

---

from your statement :

> I am getting a list of results in a map for a particular key. How to sort it?

it seems your map is

```
Map<String,List<SomeEntity>> map;
```

you can get `List` of Objects from `key` then use

```
Collections.sort(list, your_custom_implementation_of_comparator)
```

---

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<SomeEntity> {
    @Override
    public int compare(SomeEntity o1, SomeEntity o2) {
        //logic goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to sort a list, see [Collections.sort(List)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> mapie = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        mapie.put("D", "the letter D");
        mapie.put("C", "the letter C");
        mapie.put("A", "the letter A");
        mapie.put("B", "the letter B");

        Set<String> keys = mapie.keySet();

        List<String> keyColList = new ArrayList<String>();
        keyColList.addAll(keys);

            **You can also make use of a Comparator if you are using a custom object.**
        Collections.sort(keyColList);

        for(String keyIndex:keyColList){
            System.out.println("Key: "+ keyIndex + " has value: "+mapie.get(keyIndex));
        }
```

Comment: how to print the individual `keyIndex` in your for loop,can you complete that example so that it can handy for reference.

Comment: Replaced the TODO with System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this for visual inspection is to initialize a TreeMap with your map, and then print it.

```
System.out.println("map: " + new TreeMap(myMap));
```